# Problems with VBA errors

Tags: excel, vba

**DATA TABLE**

[image: DATA Table]

**Invoice Sheet**

[image: Invoice Sheet]

**Problem 1**

[image: Problem 1]

```
  Sub InvoiceForm()

    For a = 2 To 6
    For b = 2 To 3
        With ("Sheet" & b)
        .Range("E2") = Sheet1.Range("B" & a).Value
        .Range("A4") = Sheet1.Range("C" & a).Value
        .Range("B4") = Sheet1.Range("D" & a).Value
        .Range("D4") = Sheet1.Range("E" & a).Value
        .Range("E4") = Sheet1.Range("F2:G2").Value & Sheet1.Range("H2")
        End With
    Next
    Next


End Sub
```

I'm trying to extract data (sheet1) from every column of each row to 
(Sheet2 and Sheet3) using double for-loop, one is for each row and the other 
 is for the sheet number, but it apparently blocking me from doing so. The 
VBA doesn't allow running the code without specifying the Sheet number. If I 
specify each sheet number like (Sheet2,Sheet3) each time I run, the row for- 
loop would perfectly, but I have to change the sheet number each time. How 
can I solve this?

**Problem 2**

[image: Problem 2]

The other problem is that when I try to concatenate value between uneven 
columns (2 columns + 1 columns), it doesn't allow. Like in the picture, it states mismatch type. How do I solve this problem?

My goal is to run the macro once, and the program will insert values from each row and column to the designated Invoice Form (separated by Sheet number. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Images of code are not useful. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons they should be avoided. Code is text, and can be copied/pasted directly into your post here. In addition, this is a *question and answer* site. Note that *question* is singular, not plural. If you have two problems, you need to post two separate questions. You can find more information in the [help], particularly in [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Images of data are not particularly useful either. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question (but some won't download workbooks, so the other solution is generally better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the sheet syntax wrong. This should be your immediate fix, but look below for a better approach...

```
Sub invoice()

    With Sheets("Sheet" & B)

    'all your other code that was screenshot....

    End With
End Sub
```

here's a potential approach that might be a bit cleaner:

```
Sub invoice()

Dim WS As Worksheet

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If UCase(WS.Name) = "SHEET1" Or UCase(WS.Name) = "SHEET2" Then
            For a = 2 To 6
                With WS
                    .Range("E2") = Sheet1.Range("B" & a).Value
                    'etc

                'second problem
                    Dim aCell As Range, QuickText As String
                    QuickText = ""
                    For Each aCell In Sheet1.Range("F2:G2").Cells
                        QuickText = QuickText & aCell.Value

                    Next aCell
                 .Range("E4").Value = QuickText
                'end second problem solution...

                End With
            Next a
        End If
    Next WS
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you overwriting the values of E2, A4, B4, D4 and E4 each time the value of 'a' changes? I can only assume you don't intend to do that.

```
        .Range("E2") = Sheet1.Range("B" & a).Value
        .Range("A4") = Sheet1.Range("C" & a).Value
        .Range("B4") = Sheet1.Range("D" & a).Value
        .Range("D4") = Sheet1.Range("E" & a).Value
        .Range("E4") = Sheet1.Range("F2:G2").Value & Sheet1.Range("H2")
```